# Removing backslash from JSON format while programmatically constructing a JSON array

Tags: java, android, json

I want to parse the JSON data by removing the backslash from the JSON format.

I have tried removing the backslash from the JSON format by the following code but nothing worked out

```
      JSONArray packsJSON  = new JSONArray();
        JsonObject innerObject;
        for(PackageList packageList:selecteditem)
        {
            innerObject=new JsonObject();
            innerObject.addProperty("pack_id",packageList.getSubs_id());
            innerObject.addProperty("pack_dsc", packageList.getSubs_desc());
            innerObject.addProperty("pack_tax_amt", packageList.getTax_amnt());
            innerObject.addProperty("pack_grand_total", packageList.getSubs_grnd_tot_prc());


            Log.i("INNEROBJECT","hyu"+innerObject);

            packsJSON.put(innerObject);

            Log.i("PACKJSON","nkd==>>"+packsJSON)
        }
```

output of INNEROBJECT:

```
{"pack_id":"39","pack_dsc":"350 Package","pack_tax_amt":"0","pack_grand_total":"419"}
```

The output of PACKJSON:

```
 [ "{\"pack_id\":\"39\",\"pack_dsc\":\"350 Package\",\"pack_tax_amt\":\"0\",\"pack_grand_total\":\"419\"}",
  "{\"pack_id\":\"2232\",\"pack_dsc\":\"Bangara(280)\",\"pack_tax_amt\":\"0\",\"pack_grand_total\":\"280\"}"
 ]
 [
  "{"pack_id":"39","pack_dsc":"350 Package","pack_tax_amt":"0","pack_grand_total":"419"}",
  "{"pack_id":"2232","pack_dsc":"Bangara(280)","pack_tax_amt":"0","pack_grand_total":"280"}"
 ]
```

Comment: Before parsing make check the JSOn contains "/" and than after use the `YOUR_RESPONSE.replaceALL("/","");`

Comment: @RavindraKushwaha the output of innerobject is not being slashed but when we parse the innerobject to JSON array it is being slashed

Comment: What do u need at the end JSONArray OR JsonObject ???

Comment: this output:  [
  "{"pack_id":"39","pack_dsc":"350 Package","pack_tax_amt":"0","pack_grand_total":"419"}",
  "{"pack_id":"2232","pack_dsc":"Bangara(280)","pack_tax_amt":"0","pack_grand_total":"280"}"
 ]

Comment: And what is u getting now??

Comment: this output:
[ "{\"pack_id\":\"39\",\"pack_dsc\":\"350 Package\",\"pack_tax_amt\":\"0\",\"pack_grand_total\":\"419\"}",
  "{\"pack_id\":\"2232\",\"pack_dsc\":\"Bangara(280)\",\"pack_tax_amt\":\"0\",\"pack_grand_total\":\"280\"}"
 ]

Comment: Try in this way   `JSONArray packsJSON  = new JSONArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < packageList.size(); i++) {
            JSONObject innerObject = new JSONObject();
            innerObject.put("pack_id",packageList.getSubs_id());
            innerObject.put("pack_dsc", packageList.getSubs_desc());
            innerObject.put("pack_tax_amt", packageList.getTax_amnt());
            innerObject.put("pack_grand_total", packageList.getSubs_grnd_tot_prc());

            packsJSON.put(i,innerObject);


        }


        System.out.println("OUTPUT==>>> "+packsJSON.toString());`

Comment: @KiranBhagannavar please check my below answer.

Comment: @ravindraKushwaha can i share my whole code privately?

Comment: No one solution is helpful for you???

Comment: No @RavindraKushwaha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `JSONArray` is of org.json package and `JsonObject` is of com.google.gson package
so your innerObject's type should be org.json.JSONObject

```
    JSONArray packsJSON  = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject innerObject;
    for(PackageList packageList:selecteditem)
    {
        innerObject=new JSONObject();
        innerObject.put("pack_id",packageList.getSubs_id());
        innerObject.put("pack_dsc", packageList.getSubs_desc());
        innerObject.put("pack_tax_amt", packageList.getTax_amnt());
        innerObject.put("pack_grand_total", packageList.getSubs_grnd_tot_prc());


        Log.i("INNEROBJECT","hyu"+innerObject);

        packsJSON.put(innerObject);

        Log.i("PACKJSON","nkd==>>"+packsJSON)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check below answer.

```
 String jsonString = "[ "{\"pack_id\":\"39\",\"pack_dsc\":\"350 Package\",\"pack_tax_amt\":\"0\",\"pack_grand_total\":\"419\"}","{\"pack_id\":\"2232\",\"pack_dsc\":\"Bangara(280)\",\"pack_tax_amt\":\"0\",\"pack_grand_total\":\"280\"}"]"

 String outputString = jsonString.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
 Log.e("Clear String :", outputString);
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: trying it on my PC. Just a minute @RatilalChopda